# Jmeter Size of CSV file(Configure the CSV Data Source )

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter Under CSV Data Config>Configure the Csv Data source.Is there any restriction for FileSize in that.I want to know what is the range of CSV file for it .(I have a CSV file of Size of 11Mb)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is safe to say that there is no JMeter-forced restriction (at least I didn't find it in the CSVDataSet class). As for the file size, 11 MB file should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter reads the file into memory so as long as it fits in there you should be good to go. Looking into JMeter startup script, default [Java Heap](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space) setting is 512 megabytes

```
set HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
set NEW=-XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m
set SURVIVOR=-XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=50%
set TENURING=-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=2
```

So:

- Set `HEAP` to be around 80% of your total physical RAM
- Increase `NewSize` by the same factor
- Run your test without parameterization and monitor heap usage using i.e. [JVisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html)
- If your CSV file fits into remaining Heap space - you should be good to go.

I believe file size of 11 megabytes should be no brainer.

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) to learn more about tuning JMeter for maximum performance.